# Options menu won't update dynamically when using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

What I need:
Create an options menu with "Sign in" option, when user signs in it needs to change to "Sign Out" when user taps on the menu button again

When using a pure SDK i can just change the menu options in onPrepareOptionsMenu
the same works when using compatibility library v4
however when using ActionBarSherlock the menu won't update in onPrepareOptionsMenu; it still gets called, but the menu shown does not change.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this is a nasty bug in ABS.
You can fix it like this:
In FragmentActivity.java find onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) method and comment out or delete

```
if (mOptionsMenuInvalidated) {
```

line and it's corresponding closing bracket, so this block gets executed every time.
Do the same in the FragmentMapActivity activity, if you are using it.

Comment: This seems fixed in ABS 4.  Remember to call invalidateOptionsMenu() in your onTabSelected() in order to tell the system to kick off onPrepareOptionsMenu()

Comment: Since this is an older question, I'm going to go with @larham1 suggestion and assume it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is a bit old and I wasn't able to apply the suggested fix (or find a better one).  I am using ActionBarSherlock 4.2 but I still have an issue when signing in on ICS devices where the options menu is an overlay:  I couldn't figure out how to force invalidating the menu only AFTER the sign-in activity closes (and the app has determined the signed in state changed).

I resolved the issue with a flag to invalidate the menu `onResume`.  I feel like using a flag is a hack, but it's better than invalidating on every resume.

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    if ( checkLoginState == Boolean.TRUE )
    {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        checkLoginState = Boolean.FALSE;
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Then in `onOptionsItemSelected` I set the flag:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item )
{
    // Handle item selection
    switch ( item.getItemId() )
    {
        case R.id.actionbar_settings_signin_out:
            if (isUserLoggedIn() == Boolean.TRUE )
            {
                logout();
                validateOptionsMenu();
            }
            else
            {
                // set the flag so that on resume we update the options menu
                checkLoginState = Boolean.TRUE;
                startSignInActivity();
            }
            return true;
```

This is working for me but I'm curious to hear if others have solved it a better way.